# Delete Permissions for files in S3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

My app lets user login using Google Plus. I have a common bucket for all my users. Anyone can upload/download files. But the problem is anyone can delete the file. How do I set the permissions so that anyone can upload/download files, but only the user who has uploaded the file can delete the file?
This is my 
**`Roles->Inline Policy`**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::uni-cloud/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "Anyone" can upload files?  Even if not logged in to your app (if they know the bucket name)?

Comment: No I mean any authenticated user can upload the file

Comment: So, your application is generating signed URLs for user actions?

Answer (score 2):

Objects stored in Amazon S3 do not identify "the user who has uploaded the file". Therefore, you'll need some other way of identifying which files they are allowed to access.

The simplest method would be to **give each user their own sub-directory** and then grant them permission to upload/download/delete objects **only in that sub-directory**.

You could then create a Role that uses [**IAM Policy Variables**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html) that grant permission, using the user's identifier as the name for a sub-directory. The policy would look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, another quick question, What's the best way to share files among users?

Comment: It's best to post another Question, so that others can benefit from the answers. Try using products like Expandrive and Cloudberry Drive that give a Dropbox-type experience without having to learn something special for S3.

Comment: Additionally using Amazon Cognito (or Web Identity Federation) will likely make this easier for a mobile use-case.  (Check out the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/web-identity-federation.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you create folders for every user in that bucket , then you can let them delete only the objects in that folder. You can do it using IAM policies , visit [here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke)

Answer (score -1):

Upload and Delete files for specific S3 bucket

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
            "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
            "s3:GetAccessPoint",
            "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListAccessPoints",
            "s3:PutAccessPointPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:ListJobs",
            "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
            "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
            "s3:CreateJob"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketName>",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketName>/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}